# PostgreSQL: Is there a function that will convert a base-10 int into a base-36 string?

Tags: postgresql

Is there a function in PostgreSQL that can convert a base 10 number like `30` into a base 36 representation like `u`?

Comment: ints are actually binary, base 10 is only used for communication with humans..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are base-64 functions (such as [`encode`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER)) but nothing for base-36. But you could write one of your own or [use this one](http://www.rightbrainnetworks.com/blog/base36-conversion-in-postgresql/):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION base36_encode(IN digits bigint, IN min_width int = 0) RETURNS varchar AS $$
DECLARE
    chars char[]; 
    ret varchar; 
    val bigint; 
BEGIN
    chars := ARRAY['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'];
    val := digits; 
    ret := ''; 
    IF val < 0 THEN 
        val := val * -1; 
    END IF; 
    WHILE val != 0 LOOP 
        ret := chars[(val % 36)+1] || ret; 
        val := val / 36; 
    END LOOP;

    IF min_width > 0 AND char_length(ret) < min_width THEN 
        ret := lpad(ret, min_width, '0'); 
    END IF;

    RETURN ret;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
```

I think you should ask yourself if the database is the right place for dealing with this sort of data formatting though, presentational issues like this might be better handled closer to final viewing level of your stack.

Comment: Unfortunately, the linked blog post is dead. You don't happen to have such an algorithm ready for an `IN digits bytea` representation for a longer number? :-)

Comment: @LukasEder: I'm not sure what you're asking. You have a `bytea` column that you want to encode as base-36 inside the database?

Comment: if you have a bytea you want something that encodes binary data with a sensible block size like `base32` instead. base36 gets just over 31 bits into 6 characters, great for signed `int32_t`, not so useful for binary data. a block size of  31 bytes=48 characters is kind of unweildy.

Comment: you are correct, while I appreciate the solution, this sorta stuff should not be coded as functions into the db

Comment: You could use the `abs` function so save a few lines.

Comment: This function is beautiful!

Answer (score 1):

### Modified Implementation

---

Modified from other implementation to increase the readability. Any kind of **update** or **modification** or **suggestion** appreciated to increase the readability.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_base36_encode(IN base10 bigint)
    RETURNS  varchar
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    base36 varchar := '';
    intval bigint  := abs(base10);
    char0z char[]  := regexp_split_to_array('0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', '');
BEGIN
    WHILE intval != 0 LOOP
        base36 := char0z[(intval % 36)+1] || base36;
        intval := intval / 36;
    END LOOP;

    IF base10 = 0 THEN base36 := '0'; END IF;
    RETURN base36;
END;
$BODY$;
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a version that can take numbers of any size, it uses the data type "numeric" which is the postgresql implementation of bignum.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION base36_encode(IN digits numeric, IN min_width int = 0) RETURNS text AS $$
DECLARE
    chars char[] := ARRAY['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B'
                         ,'C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N'
                         ,'O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z' ] ;  
    ret text:=''; 
    val numeric:= digits; 
BEGIN
    IF digits < 0 THEN 
        val := -val;
    END IF; 

    WHILE val > 0 OR min_width > 0 LOOP 
        ret := chars[(mod(val,36))+1] || ret; 
        val := div(val,36); 
        min_width := min_width-1;
    END LOOP;
    IF digits < 0 THEN 
        ret := '-'||ret; 
    END IF; 
    RETURN ret;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
```